# Selenium web driver regular expression for <a href contains one of possible string

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to find `<a href="?" >` have any one of a list of strings for example, 
"contact", "contactus", "contactinfo", "contact".*
I have to search whether `<a href>` have those values in its path
ex path: `<a href = "http://www.site.com/contact.html"></a>`

I have already tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'CONT*')]"))
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'*')]"))
```

But it didn't solve my issue.

So how do we handle this scenario in selenium web driver using java code and is there any 
way to check equal ignorance like "contact", "CONTACT"?

Comment: `contains(@href, 'CONT*'` would match `http://www.something.com/CONTACTUS.html` but not `http://www.something.com/contactus.html`